# Python - shallow copy is not enough. Deepcopy or any alternative to improve speed?

Tags: python, dictionary, deep-copy, shallow-copy

I have this "template" dictionary:

```
_premium_per_month = {1: [0.0, []], 2: [0.0, []], 2: [0.0, []], 3: [0.0, []], 4: [0.0, []], 5: [0.0, []], 
        6: [0.0, []], 7: [0.0, []], 8: [0.0, []],
        9: [0.0, []], 10: [0.0, []], 11: [0.0, []], 12: [0.0, []]}
```

There is method that takes this dictionary and builds adding values. But when values change in shallow copied dictionary it also changes in template dict. So Should I use deepcopy or there some tips/tricks to have an alternative better/faster copy or pattern (maybe my pattern is wrong)?

And to have better understanding what it does, look at this method (it is simplified to just show the core problem)

```
def test(_premium_per_month):
  #premium_per_month = copy.deepcopy(_premium_per_month) this one works
  premium_per_month = _premium_per_month.copy() #not work
  for i in range(3):
      if i > 0:
        premium_per_month[i][0] += 20
  return premium_per_month
```

So using simple copy, of course changes original dictionary. Is deepcopy correct way to solve this problem or maybe I should change something else?

Comment: why are you copying?

Comment: Because the values in your dictionary are in the form of lists, you don't have much alternative but to use `deepcopy`. With a shallow copy, the new dictionary will just contain references to the existing lists.

Comment: Yeah, i thought so. Thanks for the input.

Comment: @Andrius, you have still not said why you are copying

Comment: @PadraicCunningham well I need that original dictionary as base. Then using it I insert values in list that originally has empty values, like `[0.0, []]`. First one is used increment float number when iterating over another object and then append that object id in second item, which is list. Then such dictionary is used elsewhere. When method is called again, that template should be empty, so thats why I'm copying it. If not, it will have previus values and it messes everything up. Also there is idea to build dictionary in method without using any template dict. Dunno which is better approach.

Comment: What is in `premium_list`? I don't quite follow how they all fit together from your example but I am pretty sure there is an easier more efficient way

Comment: It is that same list `_premium_per_month`. I will edit, to make it more clear.

Comment: yes, just create the dict in the function instead of referencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this one would be more efficient if I dropped that template approach all together (Note. showing it here that object I mentioned in comments, so it would show why I use values as list, it is called `contracts_list` and `_premium_per_month` is not used here at all)?

```
from datetime import datetime

def test(self, contracts_list):
    premium_per_month = {}
    for contract in contracts_list:
        dt = datetime.strptime(contract.date_start, self._date_fmt)
        if d.get(dt.month):
            premium_per_month[dt.month][0] += contract.premium
            premium_per_month[dt.month][1].append(contract.id)
        else:
            val_lst = [contract.premium, [contract.id]]
            premium_per_month[dt.month] = val_lst 
    return premium_per_month
```

Comment: yep, you should build a *new* dict (or a custom object if you prefer) every time, through a function like in this example; it is important you understand [Python mutable types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable).

Answer (score 0):

Just creating the dict is a lot more efficient than deep copying:

```
In [3]: %%timeit
   ...: _premium_per_month = {1: [0.0, []], 2: [0.0, []], 2: [0.0, []], 3: [0.0, []], 4: [0.0, []], 5: [0.0, []], 
   ...:         6: [0.0, []], 7: [0.0, []], 8: [0.0, []],
   ...:         9: [0.0, []], 10: [0.0, []], 11: [0.0, []], 12: [0.0, []]}
   ...: 
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.13 µs per loop

In [4]: _premium_per_month = {1: [0.0, []], 2: [0.0, []], 2: [0.0, []], 3: [0.0, []], 4: [0.0, []], 5: [0.0, []], 
   ...:         6: [0.0, []], 7: [0.0, []], 8: [0.0, []],
   ...:         9: [0.0, []], 10: [0.0, []], 11: [0.0, []], 12: [0.0, []]}

In [5]: 

In [5]: from copy import deepcopy

In [6]: timeit d = deepcopy(_premium_per_month) 
10000 loops, best of 3: 74.6 µs per loop
```

So instead of using the template, using a reference and deep copying create the dict in the function so you get a new object each time:

```
def test():
  premium_per_month = {1: [0.0, []], 2: [0.0, []], 2: [0.0, []], 3: [0.0, []], 4: [0.0, []], 5: [0.0, []], 
    6: [0.0, []], 7: [0.0, []], 8: [0.0, []],
    9: [0.0, []], 10: [0.0, []], 11: [0.0, []], 12: [0.0, []]}
```